# With the ESTA visa-waiver for the US, what if you have a reason to need more than 90 days?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, esta, visa-extensions

So I was looking at some long distance hiking trails in the US - the Pacific Crest and the Appalachian.  Both require 5-7 months to hike the whole thing.

This is fine for locals, but what about internationals needing that long to do it, when we can only get a 90 day visa?

I figure there's 3 possible outcomes:

- either there's a way to extend it,
- or you have to fly out and back in again (breaking your continuous walk :()
- or there's no way to do it, which would be disappointing.

Any solutions?

Comment: The visa waiver is, as the name says, not a visa: it's a program where you don't need a visa if you're in the USA for less than 90 days. If you're staying for longer, you need to get an actual visa. Also, you can't just hop over the border and back to get around the 90-day limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1024/~/how-to-extend-my-visa-waiver-program-stay-in-the-u.s.-if-there-is-an-emergency) you cannot extend your stay for more then 30 days and even then in the case of emergency.  The good news is that noone yet canceled availability of B1/B2 visas for the citizens of VWP countries.

So if you obtain a [B2 visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html), which you shouldn't have a problem doing you can enter the US for the period of 6 months and hike one of the trails before you have to leave the country.