# Extending my travel to the USA under VWP

Tags: esta, australian-citizens

I am an Australian citizen currently staying with friends in America on the VWP and I would like to stay a little longer. This will take me over the 90 days allowed and I'm wondering if I leave the country and go to Canada/cross a border, come back and stay with them for another 5-6 weeks.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I believe this question was previously asked and answered at *[Is it possible to extend your stay after entering the US under VWP?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73937/is-it-possible-to-extend-your-stay-after-entering-the-us-under-vwp)*

Comment: Legally speaking, you could go to Canada and apply there for a B-2 visa, which allows longer visits.  I have no idea how likely the application would be to succeed, however.

Answer (score 2):

No. Generally, going only to Canada, Mexico, or neighboring Caribbean islands and then coming back to the US will not give you a new period of admission on the Visa Waiver Program. You must go beyond those places (e.g. to Central America) to have a chance of getting a new period of admission on VWP when you get back.

Comment: And even then, getting a new 90 day period of admission on VWP is not guaranteed, if the immigration officer thinks you're doing it to circumvent the rules.